# Counting the amount of highest number in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, int

I am trying to output the amount of times the highest number appears in the user input for example user inputs 2 4 3 4 2 4 0 the highest number is 4 and it appears 3 times, not sure how to go about it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String number, last;

    System.out.println("Enter an interger (0 ends the input): ");
    number = keyboard.nextLine();
    last = number.substring(number.length() - 1);

    while(!last.equals("0")){
        System.out.println("Must end the input with a 0: ");
        number = keyboard.nextLine();
        last = number.substring(number.length() - 1);
    }

    String[] array = number.split(" ");

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxIndex = 0;

    int count;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (Integer.parseInt(array[i]) > max) {
             max = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
             maxIndex = i;
         }
    }
    //String repeat = number.);
    System.out.println("The largest number is " + max);
}
```

Comment: Well, the basic logic is simple.  For each number in the string, there are three possibilities.  (1) It's greater than the previously largest number - so store it as the largest, and reset the count to 1.  (2) It's equal to the previously largest number - so increment the count.  (3) It's less than the previously largest number - so ignore it.  All you need to do now is convert that to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Java 8's streams, e.g.:

```
String number = "2 4 3 4 2 4 0";
String[] array = number.split(" ");
TreeMap<Integer,Long> numberMap = Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(numberMap.descendingMap().firstEntry().getValue());
```

This basically stores each number and it's count into a `Map`. As the `Map` we are using is `TreeMap`, it sorts the keys in ascending order. We then get the last (i.e. highest) key from it and print the corresponding value which is 3.

Comment: That accumulates the count of all values, which is way overkill for the task at hand.

Comment: @darshan thanks man I haven't learned that yet which is why i asked

Comment: Yeah, this is going to be less efficient than the solution outlined by me and posted by @Andreas.  It's also much harder to understand.

Comment: @Andreas It iterates `Array` only once (O(n)), can be easily changed to let's say get the `min` frequency and does not use User defined class (along with lot of boilerplate code) so I would say it's not exactly an overlill.

Comment: @DarshanMehta It builds a `TreeMap`, so performance complexity is _O(n log n)_, not _O(n)_. It also requires _O(n)_ memory (worst case, _O(log n)_ average, _O(1)_ best case), while finding max can be done using _O(1)_ memory (all cases). So, with both excessive performance complexity and excessive memory complexity, I believe the word "overkill" is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are less efficient, so I'll show code for [suggested solution by David Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334111/counting-the-amount-of-highest-number-in-a-string#comment73732419_43334111):

> Well, the basic logic is simple. For each number in the string, there are three possibilities.
>
> 1. It's greater than the previously largest number - so store it as the largest, and reset the count to 1.
> 2. It's equal to the previously largest number - so increment the count.
> 3. It's less than the previously largest number - so ignore it.
>
> All you need to do now is convert that to Java.

So here it is:

```
int[] input = { 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4 };

int count = 0, max = 0;
for (int value : input) {
    if (count == 0 || value > max) {
        max = value;
        count = 1;
    } else if (value == max) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.printf("Highest number of %d was found %d times%n", max, count);
```

*Output*

```
Highest number of 4 was found 3 times
```

---

If this is something you want to do in many places, you can write your own collector and use Java 8 Streams.

Here is the use of the collector:

```
int[] input = { 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4 };

Max max = Arrays.stream(input).collect(Max::new, Max::add, Max::merge);

System.out.printf("Highest number of %d was found %d times%n", max.getValue(), max.getCount());
```

And here is the collector itself:

```
public class Max {
    private int value;
    private int count;
    public void add(int newValue) {
        if (this.count == 0 || newValue > this.value) {
            this.value = newValue;
            this.count = 1;
        } else if (newValue == this.value) {
            this.count++;
        }
    }
    public void merge(Max other) {
        if (this.count == 0 || (other.count != 0 && other.value > this.value)) {
            this.value = other.value;
            this.count = other.count;
        } else if (other.value == this.value) {
            this.count += other.count;
        }
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need to have it as int im trying to add it to the code i already have. the for loop i already have gets the max number all i need to get is the number of repeated times. the number i provided is just an example not hard code and sorry i just started learning java last week so i'm not to familiar with how things are done.

Comment: @Angel Your question is about counting occurrences of highest number, not about collecting those numbers from user, so I simply used array initializer in the *example* code to show the counting logic, and that it works. Whether the `for` loop is iterating `int` values or `double` values, or iterating `String` values and parsing them to number on the fly, is unrelated to the logic of counting max value.