# Using Stream methods in current stream method in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I got a group of Integers and I want to count the amount of `max()` integers my stream contains. The `max()` method is from within the Stream API.

I was going for something like this

```
int count = Arrays.stream(myIntArray)
            .filter(i -> i == max())
            .count();
System.out.printf("Count: %d", count);
```

I can't call the `max()` method from within my `forEach()` method since that's not how Streams function – so what can I do to make this work?

Comment: what does `max()` return?

Comment: @m_callens `max()` returns the largest Integer in the array Stream.

Comment: do you want to call the max method which belongs to the stream or your own custom max method?

Comment: I am trying to use the max() method within the Stream API, sorry. That was not clear enough.

Comment: @Aphex do you know you cannot use "count" inside the lambda because it has to be "final" for it to be allowed and you cannot change the value of "count"  when declared as "final".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do anything like this, not without a lot of hassle.  The simplest way of writing what you want would be two stages:

```
int max = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
int count = (int) Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i == max).count();
```

If you *insist* on doing it in one pass, I'd write something like

```
int[] maxAndCount = Arrays.stream(array).collect(
    () -> new int[2], // first max, then count
    (maxAndCount, i) -> {
      if (i > maxAndCount[0] || maxAndCount[1] == 0) {
        maxAndCount[0] = i;
        maxAndCount[1] = 1;
      } else if (i == maxAndCount[0]) {
        maxAndCount[1]++;
      }
    },
    (maxAndCount1, maxAndCount2) -> {
      if (maxAndCount1[0] < maxAndCount2[0]) {
        maxAndCount1[0] = maxAndCount2[0];
        maxAndCount1[1] = maxAndCount2[1];
      } else if (maxAndCount1[0] == maxAndCount2[0]) {
        maxAndCount1[1] += maxAndCount2[1];
      }
    });
  int count = maxAndCount[1];
```

...but honestly, the simple two-stage version is hard to beat.  (And frankly I'd expect it to perform better.)

Comment: @JacobG. why do you think I'm _not_ using an `IntStream`?

Comment: @JacobG. Yes.  That's why I _did_ use an IntStream.

Comment: Array#stream(int[]) returns an IntStream.

Comment: @JacobG. Read the return type of [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-)

Comment: Using `getAsInt()` means that an empty array will fail with `NoSuchElementException`, rather than result in a max count of `0` (there are no max elements, so the count of them is 0). Since OP is only interested in the count, not the max value itself, using `orElse(0)` would be better.

Comment: *Curious:* Why do you expect that iterating the array twice is faster than collecting `max` and `count` in a single iteration? If your answer is "because of index access of the `int[2]` array", then I'd say that using a class instead would fix that. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43334327/5221149) to another question.

Comment: Iterating an int array is about the fastest thing you can do. No heap variables to mess with, just a dead simple loop over integers.  That's just an educated guess, though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "No heap variables to mess with", since your code uses heap when calling the filter lambda expression. Calling the `filter()` predicate or the `collect()` accumulator is about the same thing, but the double-streaming means that you have the overhead of sending the iterated values down-stream twice, which is using the heap. --- Anyway, kinda moot point, because if you truly wanted *fast*, you wouldn't be using stream for this, just a regular `for` loop, so I agree that the two-liner is better / simpler / easier to understand, but performance is not why.

Comment: Up-voted, but I still think you should use `orElse(0)`.

Comment: @Andreas: the two-pass variant is much simpler, which in turn implies that there is a bigger chance that the code (after inlining) gets replaced with intrinsic operations by the optimizer. “get max of array” and “count occurrences” are likely recognizable patterns, whereas we can only speculate whether the optimizer will recognize either pattern within the single-pass version…

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use streams for this, you have to use an object that holds the state - you could use a custom collector for this task:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5};
    class MaxCollector {

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int count = 0;

        public void accept(int value) {
            if (max < value) {
                max = value;
                count = 1;
            } else if (max == value) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        public void combine(MaxCollector other) {
            if (max == other.max) {
                count += other.count;
            } else if (max < other.max) {
                max = other.max;
                count = other.count;
            }
        }
    }
    final MaxCollector m = Arrays.stream(arr).collect(
            MaxCollector::new, MaxCollector::accept, MaxCollector::combine);
    System.out.println(m.max + " : " + m.count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below streams code (with inline comments) as well which gives the number of occurrences (of the maximum number):

```
int maxValueCount = Arrays.stream(myIntArray).
      collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
      Collectors.counting())).//group by numbers and counts first
      entrySet().stream().//get Elements from group Map
       max((entry1, entry2) -> 
           (int)(entry1.getValue() - entry2.getValue())).//find max number in map
       get().getValue();//get the count of maximum number
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the max first, then stream it.

```
int max = Arrays.stream(myIntArray).max().getAsInt(); 

int count = Arrays.stream(myIntArray)
            .filter(i -> i == max)
            .count();
System.out.printf("Count: %d", count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the frequency method in Collections class. It exists exactly for this purpose.